# Is this joke grammatically correct?

Tags: present-perfect, translation, jokes

I am  from Hungary, I translate jokes into English
Of course, the  jokes are jokes in every language.

[image: Image of two polar bears recounting a Hungarian joke:]

> A: Mit fogsz csinálni ma? B: Semmit
> A: De hát teggnap is azt csináltad! B: Hja, de nem lettem kész vele…

I'd like to know if my translation is grammatically correct:

A: **What are u about to do today, bro?**  B: **Nothing**.
A: **But you did it yesterday too**.  B: **Yeahhh, but I have not complete it yet.**

Please send me a better variant if all is ok.

Answer (score 4):

I think that I understand the humor perfectly and I guess it's kind of funny. Your translation is totally comprehensible, but it does contain one very serious grammatical mistake. You forgot to add an *ed* on the end of *completed*. Since the verb *complete* is supposed to be used as part of a present perfect tense form, it's absolutely got to have it. Also, what's the point of writing some of the words in there in all caps? Please, don't do that. Having said that, here's my take on your joke:

> — What are you gonna do today?
>   — Nothing.
>   — But isn't that what you were doing yesterday?
>   — Yep, but I haven't finished it yet.

Comment: Thx  for  your quick  answer  . It  was  very useful  for me  .                               
The  form   "completed"  I wanted  to  use , it  stood so  in my draft ,
but  I am  not  a Profi-Tipper  .The   capitals  were  used  to  emphasize  the  word   " IT".    
You  said  that  you  understood  my  joke  but  the english  would  
never tell  anyone this joke  in such a way  like  I  translated it .
But  the  way  you  wrote  :

— What are you gonna do today?
— Nothing.
— But isn't that what you were doing yesterday?
— Yep, but I haven't finished it yet.
Once more : thx !!!